# How to find out the process or script which call php bash script

Tags: php, bash

I have php bash script that do some database processing. All I need to know is the caller of this script. I don't know if it's process or other script. So is there some way to know process id or script name of caller?

---

Script is running by some process and its code starts with interpreter path "#!/usr/bin/php". This file called as bash script only.

OS: Centos 6.5

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.posix-getppid.php

Comment: @MarcB Thanks, but I'm getting error "posix_getppid() undefined function"

Comment: So if you log in and run this script yourself with `/usr/local/bin/blah.php`, you expect to get the PID of your login shell? And if it's run from the web, you expect to get the PID of httpd?

Comment: @miken32 Script is running by some process and its code starts with interpreter path "#!/usr/bin/php". This file called as bash script only.

Comment: You didn't answer my question... And what Linux are you running?

Comment: @miken32 I expect to get nor pid of login shell neither pid of httpd. I want to get pid of process which run this php script. OS Centos 6

Comment: Try `yum install php-process` and then try @MarcB's suggestion

Comment: A bit of magic helps me to install php-process and part of unixmiah's answer solve my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
<?php

Check for a current process by filename

function processExists($file = false) {

    $exists     = false;
    $file       = $file ? $file : __FILE__;

    // Check if file is in process list
    exec("ps -C $file -o pid=", $pids);
    if (count($pids) > 1) {
        $exists = true;
    }
    return $exists;
}

?>
```

This will check against the filename that you're trying to track. If you need the process id, just adjust what's in in the exec or return the $pids.

try this ---

```
$mystring = "script_running";
exec("ps aux | grep \"${mystring}\" | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | head -1", $out);
print "The PID is: " . $out[0];
```

ps aux is more descriptive of what's running.

Comment: I've used some part of this code and it gives me no pids at all, only empty array.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I did some investigations and it works for me.